# dynamic sorting template in django

Tags: python, angularjs, django, sorting

I have problem with one idea (dynamic sort template in django)

Now I have simply solution for sorting my data but it is not so good because I have couple of buttons which adnotate to sorting view and in this way I have sorted list of my data.

I tried to use angularjs, I think this is the best way to do it but I have problem too. For example:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="sort_by = 'updated_at'">
    <button ng-click="sort_by = 'id'">id</button>
    <button ng-click="sort_by = 'created_at'">created_at</button>
    <button ng-click="sort_by = 'issuer'">issuer</button>
    <button ng-click="sort_by = 'handler'">handler</button>

    <p>{% verbatim angular %} {{sort_by}} {% endverbatim angular %}</p>

    {% for fault in faults|dictsort:{{sort_by}} %}
```

in theory it can works. but not.

I try in this way and in apostrophe and I try with another block like above {% verbatim angular %} and this is not working giving me an error like this:

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for fault in faults|dictsort:'{% verbatim angular

so it is even not recognizing angular block.

I have to ask You for help and it doesn't have to be angular, if it is better idea to do this in template or maybe stricte django way??

Thanks for help me :)

Comment: Sorting seems easiest in frontend. I have no experience with Angular, but I use the jQuery plugin **Tablesorter** for frontend sorting.

Comment: Tablesorter from jQuery works fine but I have another problem with this solution, my data are not concretly table, I have for loop of my data and show details in row div. Maybe it is not the easiest way, but for me is looking better

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you type `ng-app=""` ? You should put here name of your AngularJS application. Did You create your AngularJS module first?
2. You can sort both in frontend and backend, but You should do this in frontend - it is the job of web browser - backend should be responsible only for generating data to be consumed for frontend.
3. Something like this `{% for fault in faults|dictsort:{{sort_by}} %}` can't work. You try to define an AngularJS variable called `sort_by`, and then use it in Django filter. Django doesn't know nothing about that variable.
4. Both Django and AngularJS use `{{}}` for variable bindings in templates. You can change these symbols for AngularJS or use `verbatim` and `endverbatim` tag in Django.

Comment: like I said before, in question exactly, this doesn't work, I have error: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for fault in faults|dictsort:{% verbatim

Comment: apps is without name because it is working anyway, I have <p> tag which I test and everything is changing there, but only django says that I can't do this in this way for statement can not have something like this after dictsort

Comment: I know that it works but is poor idea. If you use AngularJS only here You can sort data in the backend and return sorted in the `context` variable during template rendering.

Comment: now it is only first step to create solution for this sorting feature and as I said in question, I do this in this way now, but I would like to have better solution, without second view, just dinamically